# Command to get name of signer from a .exe

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, digital-signature

I want to know if there is a command that will list the information that can be found in the Digital Signatures section of the properties of a .exe. Particularly I want to be able to grab the Name of the signer. Is there a command that will generate that information for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the subject name from the signer certificate used to create an Authenticode signature, you could use `Get-AuthenticodeSignature`:

```
PS > $asig = Get-AuthenticodeSignature 'C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe'
PS > $asig.SignerCertificate.Subject

CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
```

You're probably interested in the Common Name (CN), and maybe the Organization name (O). You can parse the Distinguished Name from Subject into its components to get the Common Name:

```
PS > $asig = Get-AuthenticodeSignature 'C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe'
PS > $dnDict = ($asig.SignerCertificate.Subject -split ', ') |
         foreach `
             { $dnDict = @{} } `
             { $item = $_.Split('='); $dnDict[$item[0]] = $item[1] } `
             { $dnDict }

PS > $dnDict['CN']

Microsoft Windows

PS > $dnDict['O']

Microsoft Corporation
```

Comment: The first one works perfect, how do I get the second one that will just list the CN name to run in powershell. Everytime I try to copy it over and run it gives me an error saying that system.string doesnt contain a method named TrimStart

Comment: Must be a version related issue. Updating to use TrimStart(' ') as a workaround, but you'll have to test. It's just removing the first char, a space that was after the comma.

Comment: @Technic1an, I just rewrote to remove the need for TrimStart(). Turns out I should have just used the PS -split operator. I hope this answer is acceptable to you.

Comment: Do you know if there is a Linux tool that does this also? Trying to extract the signatures using Linux cli.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd extract the signature on Linux, maybe for help see http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/Authenticode_PE.docx. Once you've extracted the signature, I'd expect you'd have to use OpenSSL, specifically PKCS7_Verify. While doable, it's not trivial and not answerable in a SO comment. But search on: authenticode signature openssl PKCS7_Verify. Good luck and let me know if you find or make a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [Sigcheck tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441) from Microsoft's Windows Sysinternals can dump the information out. Using the `-c` command line option formats the output in a csv format which can be piped to a file for later processing.

> Sigcheck is a command-line utility that shows file version number, timestamp information, and digital signature details, including certificate chains.

Comment: Csv output and show signers options are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

try `signtool.exe`. use following reference regarding signtool,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have checked that tool, unfortunately it does not provide the option to query the signer name.

Answer (score 0):

this is to output on the console:

```
      writeln(GETDOSOutput('powershell write-host =(Get-AuthenticodeSignature ''C:\Program Files\Streaming\maxbox4\maXbox4.exe'').SignerCertificate.Subject', 'C:\'));
```